# how to Draw Travelling Path between Two GeoPoint in Google Map in android

Tags: android

I want to create Travelling Path Between two geopiont.i set two point and Striate line between them but i Want to Draw Travelling Path between two point...
Thank in Advance

Comment: See this: **http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/03/sample-google-map-driving-direction.html**

Comment: This draws line on path(which exactly you want) not the straight line.

Comment: can u give one example ? please...Thanx a lot bro.

Comment: In above link find **Sample Source**, which describes 2 java files: [1]DirectionPathOverlay.java, [2]MainAcvity.java. Just create those both files in your sample project with SAME_NAME as described there, then copy the code described at there in the site to your java-files. Then just change your latitude and longitude(GeoPoint) as you have.

Comment: thanx you sir.....i also want different different point b/w souce to destination point ...any idea ??thanx again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this tutorial.

http://csie-tw.blogspot.in/2009/06/android-driving-direction-route-path.html